# Is the Prowler still in rotation?

Tags: apex-legends

I've been playing a lot since the Prowler became a care package weapon but I have rarely seen it or heard it in matches. Is it still a possible drop in care packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking an excerpt from the [Apex Legends wiki page for the Prowler](https://apexlegends.fandom.com/wiki/Prowler_Burst_PDW);

> "As a care package weapon, it can only be found in Care Packages..."

So to answer your immediate question, **yes** it still exists as a possible drop from care packages.

Now for the part you didnt ask for! Reading up on how [Care Packages](https://apexlegends.fandom.com/wiki/Care_Package) function, there are essentially different "slots" items can spawn in, and each slot has a pool of items it chooses from. The "Center" slot has a 25% chance in Round 1 to spawn a weapon and a 75% chance to choose from the "Jackpot" items. In rounds 2 and 3, this number flips. Now looking at the spawn percents for the weapons themselves, the Prowler has the highest chance to spawn over the other weapons in round 2, however round 3 would also be a good time to go looking for one as well as that is the second most likely time it would spawn. So if you want to hunt for one, I would recommend you go searching during the 2nd and 3rd round of care packages. Note that my recommendation comes from pure speculation on the percentages on the wiki. Since this is RNG we are talking about YMMV.

Comment: With every Apex Season Care packages can be tweaked, For example in Season 9 (the newest season starting now) the Care packages are changing: Triple take is replacing Peacekeeper, and appearing in early game packages. Kraber is the only permanent care package weapon in the game, but it is moving to a more midgame package, the prowler is being moved to only appear in end game packages. [The Legacy Patch notes](https://www.ea.com/games/apex-legends/news/legacy-update-patch-notes) explain the care package change in more detail. even the wiki you link is now out of date as chances changed.

Comment: "now was a good time to rebalance the drop rates of crate weapons. The Kraber will spawn less often in the early game and more often in the mid game to better accommodate its power. The Triple Take will be the most common early game crate weapon, with the Prowler being the most prominent late game crate weapon"

Comment: @Rapitor I was hesitant to write my answer because I wasnt sure if the wiki was correct and honestly I havent played this game since the very beginning of season 8. Sounds like my concern was right! Feel free to write another answer detailing the changes coming with Season 9!

Comment: Your answer is correct that Prowler is still in care package, so it's fine. I just wanted to clarify that care packages can change from season to season and the answer may become outdated. Prowler could return to the floor in season 10, for example... we don't know.